# How to create new fields based on min vals and column values in R

Tags: r, group-by, pipe, tidyverse

I have a dataframe that looks like so:

```
ID | One   |  Two   | Three

A    0.6      0.4     0.2
B    0.2      0.32    0.12
C    0.1      0.24    0.14
D    0.62     0.12    0.19
```

What I would like to do is create three new fields based on the avg value per ID, the min value per ID, and then a final column that calls the associated column header (name) associated to that min value.

Output will look something like this:

```
ID | One   |  Two   | Three  | Avg  |  Min   | Min Header

A    0.6      0.4     0.2      0.4    0.2     Three
B    0.2      0.32    0.12     0.21   0.12    Three
C    0.1      0.24    0.14     0.16   0.1     One
D    0.62     0.12    0.19     0.31   0.12    Two
```

I am currently using a group_by(ID) %>% summarise(avg = col1+col2+col3/3, min = pmin(col1,col2,col3) to create new dataframe but idk how to pull the column header as a new col in my group_by '%>%' method.

Any help would be greatly apprecaited!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option with `dplyr` where we get the 'MinHeader' based on the `max.col` index for each row after changing the numeric values to negative, then we use `rowMeans` and `pmin` to get the `mean` and `min` per row

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(MinHeader = names(.)[-1][max.col(-.[-1])], 
          Avg = rowMeans(.[2:4], na.rm = TRUE), 
          Min = invoke(pmin, .[2:4]))
```

-output

```
# ID  One  Two Three MinHeader       Avg  Min
#1  A 0.60 0.40  0.20     Three 0.4000000 0.20
#2  B 0.20 0.32  0.12     Three 0.2133333 0.12
#3  C 0.10 0.24  0.14       One 0.1600000 0.10
#4  D 0.62 0.12  0.19       Two 0.3100000 0.12
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), One = c(0.6, 0.2, 
0.1, 0.62), Two = c(0.4, 0.32, 0.24, 0.12), Three = c(0.2, 0.12, 
0.14, 0.19)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I Think I am following the code - however I am getting this error when I run it: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `MinHeader`.
x Input `MinHeader` can't be recycled to size 1.
i Input `MinHeader` is `names(.)[-1][max.col(-.[-1])]`.
i Input `MinHeader` must be size 1, not 3425615.
i The error occurred in group 1: SERIAL = "0_21". @akrun

Comment: @Dinho Is it based on the same data from my post

Answer (score 2):

If you are on `dplyr` 1.0.0 or above you can use `rowwise` with `c_across` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Avg = mean(c_across(One:Three), na.rm = TRUE), 
         Min = min(c_across(One:Three), na.rm = TRUE), 
         Min_header = names(.)[-1][which.min(c_across(One:Three))])

#  ID      One   Two Three   Avg   Min Min_header
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     
#1 A      0.6   0.4   0.2  0.4    0.2  Three     
#2 B      0.2   0.32  0.12 0.213  0.12 Three     
#3 C      0.1   0.24  0.14 0.16   0.1  One       
#4 D      0.62  0.12  0.19 0.31   0.12 Two
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `dplyr` approach

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    mat = as.matrix(across(One:Three)), # create a temporary matrix that only contains columns One to Three
    mincol = max.col(-mat),
    Avg = rowMeans(mat, na.rm = TRUE), 
    Min = mat[cbind(1:n(), mincol)],
    MinHeader = colnames(mat)[mincol],
    mat = NULL, mincol = NULL
  )
```

Output

```
  ID  One  Two Three       Avg  Min MinHeader
1  A 0.60 0.40  0.20 0.4000000 0.20     Three
2  B 0.20 0.32  0.12 0.2133333 0.12     Three
3  C 0.10 0.24  0.14 0.1600000 0.10       One
4  D 0.62 0.12  0.19 0.3100000 0.12       Two
```